# Why isn't the usual inner product defined for $P( \mathbb{R})$ valid for $C( \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The usual inner product defined for $P( \mathbb{R})$ - vector space of polynomials - is:

$\int_a^b p(t).q(t) dt$   , where $p, q ∈ P( \mathbb{R})$ and $a, b ∈ \mathbb{R} $

Why isn't this inner product valid  for $C( \mathbb{R})$ - vector space of continuous functions $\mathbb{R} ⇒ \mathbb{R}$ -  while it is valid for $C([a,b])$ ?

Comment: It's not positive definite on $C(\mathbb{R})$: there are continuous functions that vanish identically on $[a, b]$ but not on $\mathbb{R}$ (which is not true of polynomials).

Comment: Positive definite just means the product $(f, f)$ is nonnegative.

Comment: The point is there exist nonzero $f\in C(\Bbb R)$ such that $(f,f)=0$. That violates part of the definition of "inner product". On the other hand, if $f\in C([a,b])$ and $(f,f)=0$ then $f=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_a^b f(t)g(t)\,dt$, you cannot detect anything that happens outside of $[a,b]$. In particular, one of the requirements of an inner product is that $\langle f,f\rangle=0$ implies that $f=0$. If you consider functions in $C(X)$ with $[a,b]\subsetneq X$, then there exist continuous functions that are zero on $[a,b]$ but not elsewhere; such functions satisfy $\langle f,f\rangle=0$, while $f\ne 0$.

When you restrict to polynomials, on the other hand, a polynomial of degree $n$ is completely determined by its values in $n+1$ points. So if a polynomial is zero on an interval, it is zero everywhere. That's why the  product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_a^b fg$ is indeed an inner product on the set of polynomials.